# Assign expression to a variable and execute it

Tags: python

I would like to assign the following expression to a variable:

```
textFormat = 'soup.find("div", {"class" : "article-entry text"}).text.replace(\'\n\', "")'
```

I am calling this code in another file using

```
text = exec(textFormat)
```

Sadly I get the error message:

```
   File "C:\Users\dadsad\documents\coding\dasdasd\functions.py", line 42, in loadAtom
    text = exec(textFormat)   File "<string>", line 1
    soup.find("div", {"class" : "article-entry text"}).text.replace('
                                                                    ^ SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Any ideas? Thanks! :)

Edit: Tried the suggestion, getting a None:
[image]

Comment: It will need to be `\\n`

Comment: If you `print(textFormat)` and actually look at the value you assigned, you'll have a pretty good idea yourself.

Comment: The new line is interpreted and not passed to `exec`. That being said, `exec` and `eval` are antipatterns.

Comment: Yes, [`exec()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) always returns `None`. Perhaps you meant to use [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you are suffering from backslashitis. You need one more slash before the `n`:

```
textFormat = 'soup.find("div", {"class" : "article-entry text"}).text.replace(\'\\n\', "")'
```

But, instead of `exec`ing code this way, you might want expose a subroutine instead:

```
def textFormat(soup):
    return soup.find("div", {"class" : "article-entry text"}).text.replace('\n', "")
```

Comment: Tried your solution and added a screenshot. Still getting an error --> None